# Featured image fallback link to permalink

Tags: php, permalinks, post-thumbnails

I use this to display the featured image for each post. If the post does not have a featured image, a generic image will be displayed:

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    echo '</a>';
} else {
    echo '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/fallback-featured-image.jpg" />';
}
```

How can I get the fallback image to link to the permalink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated your code so that the fallback image has post permalink. I hope this helps:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
   echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >';
   the_post_thumbnail();
   echo '</a>';
} else {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" ><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/fallback-featured-image.jpg" /></a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you are trying to get the template directory. You are `getting` it instead of `printing`

`bloginfo()` **prints** the output

`get_bloginfo()` **retrieves** the output

So, the nice piece of code should look like this:

```
<?php

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    echo '</a>';
} else {
    echo '<img src="';
    echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');
    echo '/img/fallback-featured-image.jpg" />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to give a thumbs up but I am not cool enough yet :p

Comment: I've cleaned it to be free of redundant code. There was a loop which was not used.